# $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ bounded, nonempty, $\sup S \not\in S$. Prove there is a sequence $(s_n)$ in $S$ s.t. $\lim s_n= \sup S$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that we want to show there is a non-deceasing sequence $(s_n)$ of points in $S$.

Let $t= \sup S$

Since $S$ is non-empty there exists $s_1$ in $S$.

$s_1$<$t$ because $t$ is not an element in $S$.

If we let $d=t-s_1$, then $|t-s_1|<=d$

Now suppose we have a non-decreasing sequence $s_1, s_2,..., s_n$ in $S$.

I don't know how to finish this proof.

Answer (score 1):

First note that you do not need to assume that $t := \sup S$ is not in $S$. If $t$ is in $S$ you can take the constant sequence equal to $t$.

More generally, let $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. 
Suppose that for all $s \in S$ one has $t-1/n \geq s$.  Then $t-1/n \geq \sup S = t$ by definition of the supremum, hence a contradiction. 
So there exists some $s_n \in S$ such that $t - 1/n < s_n$, and one also has $s_n \leq \sup S = t$, which proves that $s_n$ tends to $t$.

Comment: Where does t-1/n>=s come from? @Paul